# How to get the jQuery validator display error message with image below field and success checked image on the right side of the input field?

Tags: jquery-validate

How can I get to display the unchecked image with error message below the required input field and also a success checked image with `ok!` next to the required input field label – not within the input field it self.

Here is what I am doing which is almost correct and this is the part that driving me nuts: In the CSS style, I try by using the `display: block;` in `em.error` and I did not get the result that I expected and I feel that was the correct way of doing it. However, I moved the `display: block;` into the `em.valid` instead and it works, but only to have the result in a flip flop state instead with the `checked image and Ok!` below the input field; and the `unchecked image with error message` next to the input field.  This is totally opposite of what I want to get.

Can you please look at my codes to see what I am doing wrong?  I want it to work with the behavior of having the `display: block;` in the `em.error` instead and with the `checked image and Ok!` on the right side or next to the input field.  Thank you.
Here is my HTML page below:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
    <title>Test HTML5</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="http://jzaefferer.github.com/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">

        input:focus { border: 1px dotted black; }
        input.error { border: 1px dotted red; }
        em.error {
            margin-left: 3px; 
            padding-left: 18px; 
            background: url("images/global/unchecked.gif") no-repeat;
            color: red;
        }
        em.valid {
            margin-left: 5px; 
            padding-left: 18px; 
            background: url("images/global/checked.gif") no-repeat;
            display: block;             
            color: green;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header"><!-- start header -->
        <div class="container"><!-- start container -->
            <div class="logoName"><h1><span></span><a rel="home" href="/" ></a></h1></div>
        </div><!-- end container -->
    </div><!-- end header -->
    <div class="container"> <!-- start container -->
        <div id="content" ><!-- start content -->
            <div id="headline"><h2>Demo Form Val</h2></div>
            <div id="CrAcct">
                <form id="newUser" class="cmxform"  name="newUser" method="post" action="#" >
                    <fieldset><legend>Create Account</legend>
                        <div class="clr-470">
                            <div class="l"><label for="userName">User Name * </label> </div>
                            <div class="r"><input type="text" id="userName" name="userName" autofocus /></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clr-470">
                            <div class="l"><label for="userEmal">E-mail * </label></div>
                            <div class="r"><input type="email" id="email" title="i.e. bob@mymail.com" class="email required" /></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clr-470">
                            <div class="l"><label for="password1">Password * </label></div>
                            <div class="r"><input type="password" id="password1" name="password1" class="password1" /></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clr-470">
                            <div class="l"><label for="password2">Confirm Password * </label></div>
                            <div class="r"><input type="password" id="password2" name="password2" class="password2 required" /></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clr-470">
                            <div class="l"><label for="blank">&nbsp;</label></div>
                            <div class="r"><input type="button" id="button" title="return to home" value="Cancel" onclick="location.href='index.html'" />&nbsp;&nbsp; 
                            <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Continue" class="submit" /></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clr-470"><hr></div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div><!-- end content -->
</div> <!-- end container -->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#newUser").validate({ 
            debug: true, 
            errorElement: "em",
            rules: { 
                userName: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 5,
                    maxlength: 10
                },
                password1: { 
                    required: true, 
                    minlength: 5,
                    maxlength: 10
                }, 
                password2: { 
                    equalTo: '#password1' 
                } 
            }, 
            success: function(label) {
                label.addClass("valid").text('Ok!');
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) { 
                alert("submitted!"); 
            }
        });
    })

</script>
<div id="footer"><br  /><!-- start footer -->
    <p>Copyright&nbsp;©&nbsp;2006&nbsp;-&nbsp;2012. All rights reserved.</p>  
</div><!-- end footer -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the CSS `em.error` insert `display: block;` and in the `em.valid` insert `display: inline;`